# How to block a third party java app from stealing focus all the time?

Tags: java, performance, windows-7, focus, focus-stealing

We use a third party java app that everytime it updates steals the focus away.  What I would like to do is isolate this single event for this single program and ignore/block it somehow.  I am willing to write a short exe to do this, but what api calls or other tools should I be using to do this.  Do I need some kind of hook?  Please help me, my internet searches have not yet born out.  We are using Windows 7.

Comment: like a **desktop version of pop-up blocker** ?

Comment: Why not let fix the third party application by its provider?

Comment: Unfortunately, asking the provider to update is not an option.  It is a program we use continously throughout the day while multi-tasking on other programs.  When the "search task" or "download task" finishes the window pops to the front and steals focus.  A desktop version of pop-up blocker would be great, not to kill the program but keep it from interrupting.

Comment: Do you know which component should have focus? If you don't I don't think there's an easy way. Unless of course you get your hands dirty with some decompiling....

Comment: What if I start it in a virtual desktop?  Would it still be able to steal the focus then?